# How to display a certain item from the set C++

Tags: c++, set

I have a set, let's say `set<string>tmpSet`. I have some elements in it,for example `10`, but I don't know what they are, because I've got this set by `set_intersection` of two another sets. Can I display for example just `first, third and eighth` element from the set?

Comment: Sure.  Use an iterator and *advance* it the appropriate amount.  Give it a try

Comment: [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) (like any other [standard container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)) can be iterated over.

Comment: bear in mind; std::set isn't as good as a std::vector for random access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
std::set<std::string> tmpSet = ...; // Create your set somehow.
// Get an iterator to the first (smallest) item in the set.
std::set<std::string>::iterator setStartIt = tmpSet.begin();
// Dereference the iterator to obtain a reference to the first element.
std::string& firstItem = *setStart;
// Get an iterator for the third element (this is two after the first!).
auto thirdItemIt = std::next(setStartIt, 2);
std::string& thirdItem = *thirdItemIt;
// Get the tenth item.
std::string& tenthItem = *std::next(setStartIt, 9);
```

Note that you can also use `std::advance()` (which modifies the iterator you pass instead of returning a new one.
Also keep in mind that this is not efficient: Since the `std::set` iterator is not a `RandomAccessIterator`, the complexity of `std::next` and `std::advance` are linear (so it will take 10 operations to get the 10th item).

If you want to look at all elements, looping over them would of course be the proper way:

```
for (auto it = tmpSet.begin(); it != tempSet.end(); ++it) {
    std::string currentElement = *it;
    ...
}
```

Or, using a range-based for loop:

```
for (auto& currentElement : tmpSet)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The elements in a `std::set` are always **in order** (sets are typically implemented as `red-black tree`).That interesting property, of course, can be used.

By using `range-based for` (since Cpp11) or search the section between `set::begin()` and `set::end()`, you can insure the elements inside.

Here is the reference http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set

Comment: @user463035818 Yes, of course, I just want to explain.why set elements are sorted. In fact, this is the basic requirement. And I haven't seen a complier implements set by another approach.

Comment: Maybe I have trouble express by using English... I mean that the elements are sorted is the basic requirement.

Comment: @user463035818 Thanks, it feels much better.

Answer (score 0):

A description of std::set can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). The key points are that

1. Elements are sorted
2. Elements are unique
3. Lookup time is O(lg2(n))
4. Insertion time is also O(lg2(n))
5. Element access bidirectional. You can iterate forwards and backward, but you can't select a random element as with `tmpSet[8]`. This means O(n) access time for random elements.

If you do want to have random access, you could use a [boost::flat_set](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost/container/flat_set.html). This has the same properties as above except

1. Insertion time is O(n)
2. Element access is random, so you can write `tmpSet[8]` which whill have O(1) complexity.